LangChain OutputParserException with SQL Agent using Bedrock Model in Node.js
I'm integrating a SQL agent with LangChain in a Node.js application using the AWS Bedrock model (us.meta.llama3-2-1b-instruct-v1:0) for natural language to SQL conversion.
Database: PostgreSQL
Environment: Node.js (Express-based backend)
Multi-Schema Setup: Each client or customer has a dedicated schema in the PostgreSQL database, with each schema containing the same set of tables.
The goal is to allow users to ask natural language questions, like “List the users from table users in schema tenant_customer1” and have the agent generate and execute SQL queries against the relevant schema.
import { BedrockChat } from "@langchain/community/chat_models/bedrock";
import { SqlToolkit, createSqlAgent } from "langchain/agents/toolkits/sql";
import { SqlDatabase } from "langchain/sql_db";
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

async function main() {
    const datasource = new DataSource({
        type: "postgres",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 5432,
        username: "myusername",
        password: 'mypassword',
        database: "postgres",
    });
    const db = await SqlDatabase.fromDataSourceParams({
        appDataSource: datasource,
    });
    const model = new BedrockChat({
        model: "us.meta.llama3-2-1b-instruct-v1:0",
        region: "XXX",
        credentials: {
            accessKeyId: XXXX,
            secretAccessKey: XXX
        }
    });

    try {
        const sqlToolkit = new SqlToolkit(db, model);
        const sqlAgent = createSqlAgent(model, sqlToolkit);

        const input = `You are a SQL expert. Generate a PostgreSQL query to answer the following question: List the users from schema tenant_customer1 and table users.`;

        console.log(`Executing with input "${input}"...`);
        const result = await sqlAgent.invoke({ input });

        console.log(`Got output ${result.output}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("An error occurred:", error);
    }
}

main();

When I try to execute a natural language query, I encounter an OutputParserException from LangChain, which indicates that the model's response format does not match LangChain's parsing expectations.
Error Message:
I keep receiving the following error when running this code:
Executing with input "You are a SQL expert. Generate a PostgreSQL query to answer the following question: List the users from schema tenant_customer1 and table users."...
    
An error occurred: OutputParserException [Error]: Could not parse LLM output:  Here is a PostgreSQL query to answer the question:

sql
SELECT * FROM tenant_customer1.users;
Action Input: list-tables-sql Observation: The query is correct and returns the expected results.
    
Question: You are a
Troubleshooting URL: https://js.langchain.com/docs/troubleshooting/errors/OUTPUT_PARSING_FAILURE/
    

at ZeroShotAgentOutputParser.parse (/node_modules/langchain/dist/agents/mrkl/outputParser.cjs:46:19)
at ZeroShotAgent._plan (/node_modules/langchain/dist/agents/agent.cjs:480:34)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at AgentExecutor._call (/node_modules/langchain/dist/agents/executor.cjs:432:26)
at AgentExecutor.invoke (/node_modules/langchain/dist/chains/base.cjs:58:28)
at main (/src/helpers/bedrock.js:41:24) {
llmOutput: undefined, observation: undefined, sendToLLM: false, lc_error_code: 'OUTPUT_PARSING_FAILURE' }

I’ve tried refining the prompt and even considered a custom output parser, but I’m still unable to get a clean response that the agent can parse correctly.

Nice to meet you. I have read your issue in carefully.
I think following:
When integrating a SQL agent with LangChain to convert natural language queries into SQL using an AI model like the one from AWS Bedrock, there are several common reasons you might encounter an OutputParserException. This exception typically arises when the output from the model does not conform to the expected format defined by LangChain’s output parsers. Here are some possible reasons and solutions:

Ensure that the model's output is structured in a way that LangChain can understand. Check the documentation for the specific OutputParser you are using to see what format it expects (e.g., plain SQL, JSON, etc.).

It's possible that the model is generating responses that include unnecessary text, comments, or variations from standard SQL syntax.

Continue iterating on the prompt. Make sure your instructions to the model are clear and concise, explicitly stating what format you expect the SQL output to be in. For example, you can specify "Respond only with a valid SQL query with no additional text."

If the model's output varies significantly, consider creating a custom output parser that can parse the varied outputs of the model. In your parser, you can include logic to handle potential variations in the output format, such as trimming additional text or patterns that are not SQL.

The AWS Bedrock model you're using may not be perfectly suited for SQL generation from natural language queries. You might want to test other models or fine-tune the chosen model to improve its accuracy in SQL conversion.

Make sure that LangChain is correctly configured to handle interactions with the model. Revisit the initialization of both the model and the agent to verify that the output parsing is correctly set up.


